# Wordpress thumbnail width/height image won't change size - stuck on 300px

Tags: wordpress, dimensions

I've tried editing the default image size for thumbnails on wordpress through settings > media, for both medium and small images, however it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

I've also regenerated the thumbnails multiple times, deleted and reuploaded them, but still they won't seem to budge from 300.

When I view the source, the thumbnails are parsing as:

> img width="300" height="300" src="

and totally ignoring the dimensions set via the admin cp.

When I change from my custom template to twentytwelve, the dimensions change from 300 to 288px.

Where are these dimensions being pulled from? It's starting to drive me nuts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code used to output your thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 200 );
```

And if you want to use different sizes, you could do this:

1.) Set the desired image size in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'smallFeaturedImage', 150, 100, true );
```

2.) Locate `the_post_thumbnail` function in the template and modify it like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'smallFeaturedImage' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your thumbnails with a plugin like this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/screenshots/